# PHP session expires even though gc_maxlifetime is set to higher value?

Tags: php, session, request, garbage-collection, token

I have massive issues concerning the php session expiration. The problem is that sessions expire after 24 minutes (which is the default value of "gc_maxlifetime" I think: 1440) even if I defined a "gc_maxlifetime" of 28800 (which is 8 hours).

When I print `phpinfo()` I get

```
session.gc_divisor: 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime: 28800
session.gc_probability: 0
```

To my understanding that means that sessions must be 8 hours valid before the garbage collector can remove them. Due to gc_divisor and gc_probability the GC shouldn't remove outdated sessions anyway.

But the problem now is that sessions timeout *before* 8 hours.

Do you have any idea how this can be?

Update:

It turned out that the hosting company ran a cronjob deleting the sessions independently from the php garbage collection.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the session being collected by GC and not just the cookie reaching its lifetime?

Comment: How are you determining that a session has expired after 24 minutes? What is the value of `expires` in the cookie that you think may be getting cleaned up by the GC?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I also thought of the cookie as a possible issue, but is has an "expires" value of "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z", i.e. it should never expire, doesn't it?

Comment: At what's especially interesting is that this cookie even after the CMS' request token is regenerated (that's the actual problem in the end) has the same PHP-Session-ID stored in the cookie.

Comment: OK, ignore my last comment. This is normal behavior (at least for Contao which is the CMS I use). Nevertheless the problem persists and the cookie seems not to be the issue since "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z" is the expire time.

Comment: Update: It turned out that the hosting company ran a cronjob deleting the sessions independently from the php garbage collection.